# React: How do you lazyload image from API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My website is too heavy because it downloads 200-400 images after fetching data from the server (Google's Firebase Firestore).

I came up with two solutions and I hope somebody answers one of them:

- I want to set each img to have a loading state and enable visitors to see the placeholder image until it is loaded. As I don't know how many images I get until fetching data from the server, I find it hard to initialize image loading statuses by useState. Is this possible? Then, how?
- How can I Lazy load images? Images are initialized with a placeholder. When a scroll comes near an image, the image starts to download replacing the placeholder.

```js
function sample() {}{
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [imgLoading, setImgLoading] = useState(true)  // imgLoading might have to be boolean[]
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).
    .then(response => setItems(response.data))
  }, [])
  return (
    items.map(item => <img src={item.imageUrl} onLoad={setImgLoading(false)} />)
  )
}
```

Comment: You may also want to associate *some* loading state with each image versus just a single overall loading state, or is that what you are actually asking about?

Comment: I want to make imgLoading[] whose length is the array length in the response from the server, but I don't know the length until I get server response.

Comment: Answer to your 2nd bullet is I think this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load

Comment: You fetch all your image urls, and your mapping each of them to display in image?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Actually I use matetial-ui's card to display, but not shown here as it's irrelevant.

Comment: Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-kare-zz6qq?file=/src/App.js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are libraries for this, but if you want to roll your own, you can use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver), something like this:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const LazyImage = (imageProps) => {
  const [shouldLoad, setShouldLoad] = useState(false);
  const placeholderRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!shouldLoad && placeholderRef.current) {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([{ intersectionRatio }]) => {
        if (intersectionRatio > 0) {
          setShouldLoad(true);
        }
      });
      observer.observe(placeholderRef.current);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [shouldLoad, placeholderRef]);

  return (shouldLoad 
    ? <img {...imageProps}/> 
    : <div className="img-placeholder" ref={placeholderRef}/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="scroll-list">
    <LazyImage src='https://i.insider.com/536a52d9ecad042e1fb1a778?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp'/>
    <LazyImage src='https://www.denofgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/power-rangers-beast-morphers-season-2-scaled.jpg?fit=2560%2C1440'/>
    <LazyImage src='https://i1.wp.com/www.theilluminerdi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/mighty-morphin-power-rangers-reunion.jpg?resize=1200%2C640&ssl=1'/>
    <LazyImage src='https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTFiODY1NDItODc1Zi00MjE2LTk0MzQtNjExY2I1NTU3MzdiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzU1NzE3NTg@._V1_CR0,45,480,270_AL_UX477_CR0,0,477,268_AL_.jpg'/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.scroll-list > * {
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.img-placeholder {
  content: 'Placeholder!';
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This code is having them load as soon as the placeholder is visible on the screen, but if you want a larger detection margin, you can tweak the [`rootMargin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin) option of the `IntersectionObserver` so it starts loading while still slightly off screen.

Comment: observer.observe(placeholderRef.current); throws typing error,* Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.ts(2345)*. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: If you're using TypeScript you'll want to do `const placeholderRef = useRef<Element | null>(null);`

Answer (score 3):

I would create an `Image` component that would handle it's own relevant states. Then inside this component, I would use [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API_) API to tell if the image's container is visible on user's browser or not.

I would have `isLoading` and `isInview` states, `isLoading` will be always `true` until `isInview` updates to `true`.

And while `isLoading` is `true`, I would use `null` as `src` for the image and will display the placeholder.

*Load only the `src` when container is visible on user's browser.*

```
function Image({ src }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isInView, setIsInView] = useState(false);
  const root = useRef(); // the container

  useEffect(() => {
    // sets `isInView` to true until root is visible on users browser

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, { threshold: 0 });
    observer.observe(root.current);

    function onIntersection(entries) {
      const { isIntersecting } = entries[0];

      if (isIntersecting) { // is in view
        observer.disconnect();
      }

      setIsInView(isIntersecting);
    }
  }, []);

  function onLoad() {
    setIsLoading((prev) => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div
      ref={root}
      className={`imgWrapper` + (isLoading ? " imgWrapper--isLoading" : "")}
    >
      <div className="imgLoader" />
      <img className="img" src={isInView ? src : null} alt="" onLoad={onLoad} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would also have CSS styles that will toggle the placeholder and image's `display` property.

```css
.App {
  --image-height: 150px;
  --image-width: var(--image-height);
}

.imgWrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img {
  height: var(--image-height);
  width: var(--image-width);
}

.imgLoader {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

/* container is loading, hide the img */
.imgWrapper--isLoading .img {
  display: none;
}

/* container not loading, display img */
.imgWrapper:not(.imgWrapper--isLoading) .img {
  display: block;
}

/* container not loading, hide placeholder */
.imgWrapper:not(.imgWrapper--isLoading) .imgLoader {
  display: none;
}
```

Now my Parent component, will do the requests for all the image urls. It would also have its own `isLoading` state that when set `true` would display its own placeholder. When the image url's request resolves, I would then map on each url to render my `Image` components.

```
export default function App() {
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages().then((response) => {
      setImageUrls(response);
      setIsLoading((prev) => !prev);
    });
  }, []);

  const images = imageUrls.map((url, index) => <Image key={index} src={url} />);

  return <div className="App">{isLoading ? "Please wait..." : images}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-kare-zz6qq]

Answer (score 0):

Map the response data to an array of "isLoading" booleans, and update the callback to take the index and update the specific "isLoading" boolean.

```
function Sample() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [imgLoading, setImgLoading] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;
      setItems(data);
      setImgLoading(data.map(() => true));
    });
  }, []);

  return items.map((item, index) => (
    <img
      src={item.imageUrl}
      onLoad={() =>
        setImgLoading((loading) =>
          loading.map((el, i) => (i === index ? false : el))
        )
      }
    />
  ));
}
```